# ASP.NET MVC PartialView get html string

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

Is there a way to get the Html string from a PartialView inside the controller?

I have an odd scenario where I need to return some extra data along with the partial view to deal with error conditions.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
 return Json( 
     new { 
         status = "OK", 
         content = PartialView("Orders", model).ToHTML() 
     });
```

I did find a similar question on here but none of the solutions were very clean and as that question is over 2 years old now I thought I'd see if there is any better way in MVC2.0.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an Action along with RenderAction to accomplish that.
More information in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728607%28v=VS.98%29.aspx), [here](http://nosuchblogger.com/post/58/aspnet-mvc2-renderaction) and in [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).